# Fetch value of People Picker on List forms through Jquery in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, people-picker

[image]

How to extract people picker value so that i can use it in code dynamically on Edit Form page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that you can use

```
$('.ms-entity-resolved[id^="txt_MentorName"]').attr('title');
```

Or

Copied From - https://blog.sprider.org/2012/04/23/get-sharepoint-people-picker-value-using-java-script/

```
var PickerPerson = getPickerInputElement("ff13"); // Here ff13 is your people picker control ID

function getPickerInputElement(identifier) {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(‘DIV’);
    for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tempString = tags[i].id;
        if ((tempString.indexOf(identifier) > 0) && (tempString.indexOf(‘UserField_upLevelDiv’) > 0)){
            var innerSpans = tags[i].getElementsByTagName(“SPAN”);
            for(var j=0; j < innerSpans.length; j++) {
                if(innerSpans[j].id == ‘content’) {
                    return innerSpans[j].innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is giving undefined by using this.

Comment: Did you put the correct field Name? Please use browser tool to find it

Comment: $('ms-inputuserfield[id="ctl00$m$g_332d4490_608a_44d1_9ce9_572cdcceba13$ff1_1$ctl00$ctl00$UserField$downlevelTextBox"]').attr('title');       i used this id from F12 for the div containing the people picker, still getting undefined.... should i use different id

Comment: Can i write this code in sp designer aspx page?

Comment: Yes you can edit the form in advanced mode.. another option is to edit the page in browser and add a content editor webpart

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this to get people picker value

```
<script src="/JSLibrary/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[title='JM ID']").focus(function()   {
var User = $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val().split("\\");
$("input[title='JM ID']").val(User[1]);
});
});
```

[Ref](https://ronsp.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/get-value-from-people-picker-using-jquery/)

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: what should i write at the place of 'JM ID'... or as it is

Comment: your control in edit form